# Best comma (,) alternatives for large, complex .csv datasets

Tags: python, database, windows, csv, database-design

Instead of comma (`,`), what is the best alternative single character or string to use in `.csv` files that are regularly processed as columns and rows (like a table)? My values do contain an unpredictable number and pattern of commas.

Needs compatibility with python (and preferably) other applications.  Often my values contain comma `.` so I have been using `","`, or rather, the  `"value"` pattern. I am using now:

```
"column1","column2","column3"
```

However, it is often a pain to make the `"` work correctly in these cases.

**For example** to reorder csv columns with `","`:

```
import csv

infilename = input('Enter .csv to rearrange: ')

with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open('reordered__'+ infilename, 'a') as outfile:
    fieldnamesout = ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D']
    fieldnamesin = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', fieldnames=fieldnamesin)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', fieldnames=fieldnamesout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Vertical line `|` , or maybe star `*` seems to be a good single character choice as they are not permitted in directory and filenames and are *relatively* rare in "regular" text.

**Q:** Any suggestions what to use for large, complex databases stored as text where value contain comma and other unusual characters? Any cons of using vertical lines (`|`) instead of comma (`,`)?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special if your values contain commas. The CSV reader and writer handle that for you, right?

Comment: no. comma (`,`) in values wreck the handling all the time (incorrect column recognition, incorrect column numbers, incorrect [partial] values], etc.)

Comment: Wreck the handling where? If you always use a proper CSV reader/writer, there shouldn't be a problem. In fact, that is the whole reason for using CSV libraries instead of manually splitting on commas.

Comment: I agree with @Blurp I think the question that would be better to answer would be why are you having trouble making it work with " ?

Comment: if x number of lines contain 5 commas, y number of lines contain 4 commas, z number of lines 6 commas. how many columns do you have by design? ( values contain variable number of commas)

Comment: Well, if the data is properly formatted/escaped for CSV, then that question is easy to answer. If it's not, then it's impossible to say (and using a different separator probably won't help in the latter case).

Comment: i do see work around solutions for the `","` separator, but they an additional coding step and their handling may differ among programs. is there a downside using `|` instead?

Comment: ok, "escaped for CSV" is a major answer here. can you elaborate? is this cross-platform/program? why escaping is easier than simply uising `|`?

Comment: If you're using a CSV library (like you are), it will do escaping/quoting automatically for you. And, yes, it's cross-platform. If you use `|`, there still may be situations where escaping/quoting is necessary. The chances might be less than with `,`, but that's not something I personally would rely on.

Comment: if escaping happens and you import into notepad++ or other text processors, would net they fail to recognize escaping?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to consider commas in a CSV when you are using commas to parse is by enclosing the values that contain commas within double quotes (" ").

For example, if you have a CSV file with the following data:

```
Name, Age, Occupation
John, 25, Programmer
Mary, 32, Sales Manager
Tom, 28, Software Engineer, Team Lead
```

The third row of data has a value "Software Engineer, Team Lead" with a comma in it, which could cause issues with CSV parsing. To escape the comma, you can enclose the value within double quotes like this:

```
Name, Age, Occupation
John, 25, Programmer
Mary, 32, Sales Manager
Tom, 28, "Software Engineer, Team Lead"
```

If there are double quotes within a value that is already enclosed in double quotes, you can escape them by doubling them up. For example, consider the following CSV data:

```
Name, Age, Occupation
John, 25, Programmer
Mary, 32, Sales Manager
Tom, 28, "Software Engineer, Team Lead, ""Project Manager"""
```

I use PowerBasic and wrote a function called "eCSV" (escape csv):

```
' escape values for csv
' replace " with "" and wrap with ""
Function eCSV(ByVal s As String) As String   
   Replace $Dq With $Dq+$Dq In s
   s=$Dq+s+$Dq   
   Function=s
End Function
```

and when writing my CSV I call like this:

```
' write line
temp=eCSV(designation)+","
temp+=eCSV(glb)+","
temp+=eCSV(sampleID)+","
temp+=eCSV(clientName)+","
temp+=eCSV(clientID)+","
temp+=eCSV(belongsTo)+","
temp+=eCSV(saveDate)+","
temp+=eCSV(arDate)+","
temp+=eCSV(artFrom+" - "+artTo+" "+artCF)+","
temp+=eCSV(subID)+$crlf
 
print #fNumber, temp
```